# electron js app after build shows error "cannot load local resources"

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

i have tried so many solution from internet and chatGPT but none of them worked i am exhausted can any expert help?

when i run "electron ." app runs perfectly but after build it shows white screen and this error.

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Applications/Brahmani/brahmani/dist/mac-arm64/brahmani.app/Contents/Resources/app/build/build/index.html`

also this image shows warning while running app without build

[image of warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2FeM.png)

this is code i have in electron main file

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');



let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1300,
    height: 1000,
    icon: path.join(__dirname,"/logo.png"),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

config

```
{
  "name": "brahmani",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "main.js",
  "description": "local app",
  "author": "me",
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^27.1.3",
    "electron-builder": "^24.9.1"
  }
};
```

react app tools

```
{
  "name": "brahmani",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.15",
    "serve": "^14.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "build": {
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "build",
      "app": ""
    },
    "files": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

i have used electron-builder for building electron app

**i have router installed in react but never used in app**

i have tried around 20 different methods and changed my code a lot of time nothing is working i think it's a easy error but i am not getting it and also i have my electron app and react app in same folder and both apps share a single package.json and it shouldn't be the problem because i already have one app running with same structure.

Comment: You have not provided enough information, please share your packager config and how/what you use to build your app. Also, just to make sure you are aware, enabling `nodeIntegration` is a [security risk](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content).

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information, do not add it in the comment. You also have not tell what tool you use dot build the React app.

Comment: @Arkellys is it okay now please tell me if there is something i am doing wrong cause it's first time i am using this site

Comment: Yes it is, thanks, I will try to answer

Comment: @Arkellys i just got it solved so the solution was that instead of keeping my react app build files in separate folder i placed files in the same directory as main file and it worked.

Comment: Hmm, I will still post my answer because I spent +1 hour to write it to give additional explanations

Comment: yes, thank you very much for this, it will help me understand electron app building and about it's configs